# Change default sender email address in ABP SmtpEmailSender

Tags: asp.net, aspnetboilerplate

I'm using the ASP.NET Boilerplate framework to send mail notification. I want to change the sender mail address based on the scenarios(one for Employees and another one for End Users)

Please advise me how to change sender mail address at run time (other than from default configuration).

```
mailSender.SendAsync(
  to: toEmailAddress,
  subject: mailSubject,
  body: mailBody,
  isBodyHtml: true);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 2 ways:

1. `IEmailSender` has an [overloaded method](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/da0880a93d11e9f144d0f9f56b1492578ab9c3a3/src/Abp/Net/Mail/IEmailSender.cs#L24) that takes in a `from` parameter:

   ```cs
   mailSender.SendAsync(
     from: isEmployee ? employeeSenderEmailAddress : endUserSenderEmailAddress,
     to: toEmailAddress,
     subject: mailSubject,
     body: mailBody,
     isBodyHtml: true);
   ```
2. You can subclass `SmtpEmailSenderConfiguration`, inject `IAbpSession` and override `UserName` getter. This way, you abstract the email address logic.

   ```cs
   public override string UserName
   {
       get
       {
           var isEmployee = AbpSession.UserId == 0; // Example
           return isEmployee ? employeeSenderEmailAddress : endUserSenderEmailAddress;
       }
   }
   ```

   Remember to replace the services in the `PreInitialize` method of your module:

   ```cs
   Configuration.ReplaceService(typeof(IEmailSenderConfiguration), () =>
   {
       IocManager.IocContainer.Register(
           Component.For<IEmailSenderConfiguration, ISmtpEmailSenderConfiguration>()
               .ImplementedBy<MySmtpEmailSenderConfiguration>()
               .LifestyleTransient()
           );
   });
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below method of `IEmailSender` in abp.dll. Refer [API Document](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/api-docs/html/M_Abp_Net_Mail_IEmailSender_Send_2.htm).

```
void Send(
string from,
string to,
string subject,
string body,
bool isBodyHtml = true
```

)

You just need to set `from` and `to` parameter as per your requirement.

You can differentiate between employees and other users based on role or permissions.